# How can I replace a new line with "+" character?

Tags: python

I need to send an SMS to my phone using the Nexmo API. I make Python code to send the SMS. The text message should not have spaces.

Example:

`https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=******&api_secret=******&from=Test&to=973272833&text=Hi+how+are+you`

I have code such that when I send an SMS, all spaces are replaced by `+`:

```
node=urllib2.urlopen(u"https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=****&api_secret=****&from=OmanActivation&to=" +str(PhoneNumber)+ "&text=" +Message.replace(" ", "+"))
```

But if my message has a line break:

for example:

> Hi.
> How are you?

How can I replace the line break with `+` and still make the message show up with a line break like as in the example?

If I replace "\n" by "+" it will appear as:

> Hi.How are you?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`urllib.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) for this task.

Comment: Can you tell me how i can use urllib.quote_plus in my code?<br>Because I'm new with python

Comment: No I will not spoonfeed you, time to read the docs and try it yourself good luck

Comment: It should be no problem to follow the link to the documentation. There is no need to copy the documentation to this place.

Comment: I'd actually suggest using `urllib.urlencode` to build the whole query string (everything past the `?` in the URL), rather than using `quote_plus` and string formatting operations. `urlencode` uses `quote_plus` internally, so newlines (and spaces) will be taken care of automatically.